# Delayed DLL directive causing application deadlock on FireDAC query

Tags: delphi, dll, deadlock, delphi-xe5, firedac

I have an application set up in the following manner in Delphi XE5:

main.exe: calls a function in sub.dll using the export delayed directive

```
function MyFunction: boolean; external 'sub.dll' delayed;
```

sub.dll: contains a FireDAC query object which runs a simple SELECT query.

Upon opening the query, with the delayed directive the application does not terminate when the main form is closed (process main.exe remains in task manager). Process explorer shows a thread remaining for sub.dll. The main.exe process terminates correctly when I do not specify the delayed directive. What am I missing? I feel like I'm not freeing an object but I can't figure out what it is.

Simplified code:

Main.exe:

```
program Main;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils;

  function MyFunction: boolean; external 'Sub.dll' delayed;

begin
  try
    MyFunction;
  except
    on E: Exception do begin
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
      readln;
    end;
  end;
end.
```

Sub.dll

```
library Sub;

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  System.Classes,
  DBConn in 'DBConn.pas';

{$R *.res}

function MyFunction: boolean; export;
var Conn: TConn;
begin
  Conn := TConn.Create;
  Conn.Destroy;
  Result := True;
end;

exports
  MyFunction;

begin
end.
```

DBConn.pas

```
unit DBConn;

interface

uses
  FireDAC.Stan.Intf, FireDAC.Stan.Option,
  FireDAC.Stan.Error, FireDAC.UI.Intf, FireDAC.Phys.Intf, FireDAC.Stan.Def,
  FireDAC.Phys, FireDAC.Stan.Pool, FireDAC.Stan.Async, FireDAC.Stan.Param,
  FireDAC.DatS, FireDAC.DApt.Intf, FireDAC.DApt, FireDAC.VCLUI.Wait,
  FireDAC.Comp.UI, FireDAC.Phys.ODBCBase, FireDAC.Phys.ASA, Data.DB,
  FireDAC.Comp.DataSet, FireDAC.Comp.Client;

type
  TConn = class
    FDConnection: TFDConnection;
    FDQuery: TFDQuery;

    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

var
  Conn: TConn;

{ TConn }

implementation

constructor TConn.Create;
begin
  FDConnection := TFDConnection.Create(nil);
  //Set database connection parameters
  with FDConnection do begin
    close; Params.Clear;
    Params.Add('DriverID=ASA');
    Params.Add('Database=');
    Params.Add('Server=');
    Params.Add('USER_NAME=');
    Params.Add('PASSWORD=');
    open;
  end;
  FDQuery := TFDQuery.Create(nil);
  with FDQuery do begin
    Connection := FDConnection;
    close; unprepare; SQL.Clear;
    SQL.Add('Select first LAST_NAME');
    SQL.Add('From USERS');
    SQL.Add('Order By LAST_NAME');
    prepare; open; //this causes the deadlock
    writeln(Output, FieldByName('LAST_NAME').AsString);
  end;
end;

destructor TConn.Destroy;
begin
  FDConnection.Close;
  FDConnection.Free;
  inherited;
end;

end.
```

Comment: Do you get the same result with an empty TMyForm.ButtonClick handler?  If not, exactly which steps of the existing handler are necessary to get the thread remaining?

Comment: @MartynA do you mean if i move move the query into say, the formshow? yes, the same result occurs.

Comment: No, I was meaning if you don't open the FDConnection and FDQuery at all.

Comment: @MartynA I can open the FDConnection without problems. As noted in the code, the open statement for the FDQuery is what causes the deadlock as far as I can tell. If I exclude the open statement the application terminates normally. I have a sample project i can upload somewhere if that'd help.

Comment: Am I reading this right - the app's main form is being closed while `MyFunction()` is still running?  Is `MyFunction()` being called in a worker thread, or in the app's main UI thread?  You cannot safely use UI forms/controls in worker threads. And a modal form running inside a DLL is not going to dispatch VCL messages intended for a form that is running outside the DLL.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I'm not sure what you mean. The main form calls the modal form in the dll (using a buttonclick). The modal form calls the query procedure and finishes executing it (also using a buttonclick). The modal form is then closed (by setting ModalResult = mrOK) which returns it to the main form. The main form is then closed (Application.Terminate). Without the delayed directive on the external dll call the application terminates correctly. With the delayed directive the form closes but the process remains.

Comment: The ONLY difference between using `delayed` or not is that `delayed` loads the DLL via `LoadLibrary()` and the `MyFunction()` pointer via `GetProcAddress()` the first time it is called at runtime, whereas lack of `delayed` causes the DLL and function pointer to be loaded at process startup before any app code starts running. There is nothing in those different procedures that would cause the problem you describe. The DLL doesn't care if it is loaded statically or dynamically. Something else has to be going on, not related to `delayed` itself. Did you try debugging the DLL yet?

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes, that's what I understood the difference to be as well, which is why I am stumped as to what's causing the deadlock behavior only when delayed is set. I have tried debugging the DLL as well as the executable but was not able to make sense of the resulting information other than that there was a block on a critical section by the main form. I've updated the question with full code to reproduce the behavior.

Comment: Can you remove all the db related code and still encounter the problem? Is this really a minimal example?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yes, this is minimal. As stated in the code, the problem occurs only after opening the query. Without opening the query, the application terminates as expected. I can't exactly remove querying from the application though...

Comment: So the interaction between delay loading and the DB access would appear to be key. If I were you I'd make a reduced example code that removes any VCL components. That way you could avoid what appears to be the mis-direction of Torbins' answer.

Comment: @DavidHefferman I tried this, but I'm not sure I did it right. Updated post with code. Behavior seems similar: the console window remains open with the delayed directive, but closes immediately without it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a FireDAC limitation. See http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/DLL_Development_(FireDAC)#FireDAC_DLL_Unloading

Comment: But perhaps you edit your q down, to make it much shorter and make clearer what are the necessary and sufficient conditions to encounter the problem.

Comment: Done. Thanks for the help

Answer (score -3):

VCL will **reliably** work in Dll **only** if your main Exe and Dll are compiled in the same version of Delphi with runtime packages enabled for them.

Comment: That is an oversimplification and is in fact not true. Classic counter example to prove your statement wrong is an Office COM add-in.

Comment: Seen that. Doesn't work reliably. I mean you should carefully choose components that work OK inside such add-in. And the list of such components is not big.

Comment: Not at all. Office COM add-ins written in VCL work well. As evidenced by the success of this: https://www.add-in-express.com/add-in-delphi/index.php

Comment: What @DavidHeffernan says.  And how do you account for e.g. the different versions of MSXML Delphi can work with?

Comment: @David Heffernan That is a set of specialized components that work OK only with MS Ofice. How should that prove that in general using VCL in Dll is not dangerous and prone to bugs?

Comment: That's not true. You can use pretty much any VCL component in a DLL. For sure there are issues, but they are not what you describe. Passing objects from EXE to DLL is a problem of course. That's not safe. And there are issues with a message loop in one module dispatching to objects in another module. Anyway, I'm sure that you can see now that the issue at hand, in this question, is something else entirely.